# Avahi quits working after a few minutes on FreeBSD/FreeNAS

Tags: freebsd, freenas, bonjour, avahi

As I mentioned [in another post](https://superuser.com/questions/681464/cups-auto-discovery-not-working-on-freebsd-freenas), I've set up a portsjail on FreeNAS 9.1.1 (FreeBSD 9.x) with CUPS and avahi. I'm trying to set up AirPrint support. I've gotten to the point that a Mac can see the avahi advertised printer, but once it runs for a few minutes, the service disappears and is unavailable until I restart avahi-daemon. Nothing unusual seems to occur if I run avahi-daemon in debug mode:

```
# avahi-daemon --debug                                                          
Found user 'avahi' (UID 200) and group 'avahi' (GID 200).                       
Successfully dropped root privileges.                                           
avahi-daemon 0.6.29 starting up.                                                
Loading service file /usr/local/etc/avahi/services/AirPrint-Brother.service.    
Loading service file /usr/local/etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service.            
Loading service file /usr/local/etc/avahi/services/ssh.service.                 
Joining mDNS multicast group on interface bge0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.202. 
New relevant interface bge0.IPv4 for mDNS.                                      
Network interface enumeration completed.                                        
Registering new address record for 192.168.1.202 on bge0.IPv4.                  
Registering HINFO record with values 'AMD64'/'FREEBSD'.                         
Server startup complete. Host name is cups.local. Local service cookie is 842584
827.                                                                            
Service "cups" (/usr/local/etc/avahi/services/ssh.service) successfully establis
hed.                                                                            
Service "cups" (/usr/local/etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service) successfully est
ablished.                                                                       
Service "AirPrint Brother @ cups" (/usr/local/etc/avahi/services/AirPrint-Brothe
r.service) successfully established.
```

No further messages appeared -- even after avahi's services disappeared from Bonjour Browser -- until I pressed Ctrl-C to shut down the daemon. Then it shut down apparently normally:

```
^CGot SIGINT, quitting.                                                         
Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface bge0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.202. 
avahi-daemon 0.6.29 exiting.
```

Any suggestions on what I need to tweak to keep avahi from repeatedly shutting down?

Comment: Interestingly, this does not occur if I advertise the service directly in the host FreeNAS's avahi instead of the jail's copy of avahi.

Comment: I wrote up more on what did and did not work in [a related post](http://superuser.com/questions/673880/airprint-and-airplay-on-freenas). I still haven't figure out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem